# Extracting ancestors upto "me"

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Given

```
class Bird
  def self.bird_ancestors
    ancestors.first(ancestors.find_index(Bird)+1)
  end
end

class Duck < Bird
end

class FeatheredDuck < Duck
end

FeatheredDuck.bird_ancestors => [FeatheredDuck,Duck,Bird]
Duck.bird_ancestors => [Duck,Bird]
Bird.bird_ancestors => [Bird]
```

How can I reference the `Bird` within `Bird` without having it be explicit? I know `self` and `__class__ doesnt` work.

Comment: The ordering of your class definitions is wrong.

Comment: Also, what you mean by "`self` doesn't work"? Inside a class method, `self` refers to the current class.

Comment: Also, you seem to be presenting so much things irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @sawa, you may have misunderstood the question.  Note the title.

Comment: You can do this by `select`ing elements of `ancestors` that `respond_to? __method__`.

Comment: @cary sweet! Write your answer to get 25 points!

Comment: `take_while` instead of `select`

Comment: I will, a little later.  Busy now.  I think `take_while` and `select` are equivalent here.

Comment: Assuming a longing ancestory of `Bird`, I would like to stop looking further up than `Bird`. `take_while` will stop after looking at the next one up.

Comment: Yes, Aditya, `take_while` will stop looking. `select` will keep looking, but won't find any more. If you are unsure, think of it this way: if C were the highest class found by `select`, `take_while` would return all ancestors up to and including `C`.

Comment: is there a __class__ method in ruby?? Sorry for digging this out, I am just curious

Comment: I meant `__class__` method, and can you share a link to the documentation of the method, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
class Bird
  def self.bird_ancestors
    ancestors.take_while { |c| c.respond_to? __method__ }
  end  
end

class Duck < Bird
end

class FeatheredDuck < Duck
end

FeatheredDuck.bird_ancestors #=> [FeatheredDuck, Duck, Bird]
Duck.bird_ancestors          #=> [Duck, Bird]
Bird.bird_ancestors          #=> [Bird]
```

`select` also works, but `take_while` (suggested by @Aditya) is better because it stops searching `ancestors` once `false` is returned from the block.

Comment: why use `__method__` when we know the method name already? I mean it is static.

Comment: @SachinSingh, one reason and one reason only: if in future the name of the method is changed one does not have to remember to change the body of the method as well. (Good question though.)

Answer (score 2):

Inside a class method, `self` refers to the current class object:

```
class Bird
  def self.foo
    self
  end
end

p Bird.foo # => "Bird"
```

Comment: This doesn't do it.  The asker wishes to extract ancestors though Bird.

Comment: @agis you are right but for `Duck.foo` and `FeatheredDuck.foo` it would resolve to `Duck` and `FeatheredDuck` and not `Bird` which his what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
class Bird
  def self.bird_ancestors
      class_name =  method(__method__).owner.to_s.gsub(/#<Class:|>/,'')
      ancestors.first(ancestors.map{|x| x.to_s}.find_index(class_name)+1)
  end
end

(__method__ is the current method)
```